# Add a command to user terminal profile?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, .bash-profile

Every time I start a new terminal, I have to type `nvm use 4.1.1` to get my node version selected. Is there a way to get this to be 'typed' or added to some environment variable when I open a new terminal?

I've heard of 'bash_profile' but I'm still new to linux, and I don't know if this is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "nvm use 4.1.1" >> ~/.bashrc
```

will append `nvm use 4.1.1` to the end of your `.bashrc` file. `~/.bashrc` is a file containing commands that Bash will run at the beginning of every interactive session.

`~/.bash_profile` is similar, however, it only runs while a login shell is starting up (`~/.bashrc` also runs here). `~/.bashrc` is the one you probably want.

Comment: Great! exactly what I was looking for.